# Caching with Symfony2 and Doctrine - which one to use? Is phpFastCache an option?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

this is a general and a specific question about an application built on Symfony (2.7) and Doctrine (2.5) planned to be pushed to 2 different PHP PaaS platforms.

**General part:**

I am developing locally with a most current PHP version (don't want to use an older version), but the two buildpacks of my PHP PaaS platforms are offering a modern 5.4 PHP only.

I want to achieve both bytecode caching (of course) and object/var caching as well.

Understanding that APC is not valid anymore since 5.4 (but still has the best "built-in" support by Symfony) and not finding any general caching mechanism which offers bytecode AND object caching I ended up trying to implement http://www.phpfastcache.com/ as my caching mechanism - by that I hoped to get it running on both 5.4 platforms (still allowing APC in one and xcache in the other case).

Before I get into my trouble how to get phpfastcache running with Symfony/Doctrine:

Is anyone aware of any caching module which is stable, supported by Heroku/Cloudfoundry (standard PHP buildpacks - for me it doesn't make sense to build my one buildpack loosing partly the advantages of a Paas) and running on > PHP 5.4 ideally supporting bytecode and object caching?

**Specific part:**

https://gist.github.com/thephoenics/ee7de9f95bfdf5f6c24f looked very promising to me!

I tried to use this by:

**1) implementing my PhpFastCacheProvider.php**

This is intended to implement all methods from Doctrine CacheProvider as well from Validator CacheInterface.

```
<?php

namespace My\MyBundle\Cache;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\CacheInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use phpFastCache;

class PhpFastCacheProvider extends CacheProvider implements     CacheInterface
{
public function __construct()
{

    if (extension_loaded('apc') && ini_get('apc.enabled') &&     strpos(PHP_SAPI, "CGI") === false) {
        $driver = "apc";
    } elseif (extension_loaded('xcache') && function_exists("xcache_get")) {
        $driver = "xcache";
    } else {
        $driver = "auto";
    }

    phpFastCache::setup("storage", $driver);

}

public function doDelete($id)
{
    __c()->delete($id);
}

public function doFlush()
{
    __c()->clean();
}

public function doGetStats()
{
    return __c()->stats();
}

public function has($class)
{
    return $this->doContains($class);
}

public function doContains($id)
{
    return __c()->isExisting($id);
}

public function read($class)
{
    return $this->doFetch($class);
}

public function doFetch($id)
{
    $a = __c();

    $b = $this->doGetStats();

    $value = __c()->get($id);
    if ($value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return $value;
}

public function write(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $this->doSave($metadata->getClassName(), $metadata);
}

public function doSave($id, $data, $lifeTime = 0)
{
    __c()->set($id, $data, ($lifeTime == 0) ? 24 * 3600 : $lifeTime);
}
```

**2) Register my class as a service**

```
    phpfastcache:
    class: My\MyBundle\Cache\PhpFastCacheProvider
```

**3) Update config.yml to use it**

```
framework:
    validation: {enable_annotations: true, cache: phpfastcache }
doctrine:    
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: phpfastcache
        result_cache_driver:
        type: service
            id: phpfastcache
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: phpfastcache
```

- xcache is installed locally and even running for PHP CLI (checked by setting some var in xcache from my code and verifying it in xcache admin console).
  I verified as well that $driver is 'xcache' - no issue here.
- symfony and doctrine start up - no issue so far.
- but: as I don't fully understand how phpFastCache and the magic __c() is getting instantiated somehow any time only 'files' is used as config/storage - and I don't get why.

Do I need to register phpFastCache anywhere else?
When and how should I initiate it? (but Symfony and Doctrine are doing it earlier of course before I call new PhpFastCacheProvider() for the first time in my code to cache some app results.

Does anyone have any idea?

I generally like the idea of phpFastCache to basically wrap some common cachers for PHP with its fallback strategy as caching in PHP is a pain (see general part :-).

Thanks for any support.